# How should I construct a random challenge for challenge-response authentication?

Tags: c, security, authentication, random

I am reviewing the implementation of a cryptographic challenge-response protocol.  The password is used as the key to encrypt a cryptographic nonce (the challenge), and the result is compared with the response.

Currently, the nonce is not really secure as it is obtained with `srand()` and `rand()`. All of the ingredients of the random number seed (the current time in seconds (!) and the pid) are quite easy to guess for a man in the middle.  This is obviously not good but my question is, how bad is this at preventing replay attacks? Should the challenge be obtained from a CSPRNG (such as /dev/urandom)? Does anybody have any pointers to best practices?

Comment: `/dev/urandom` is probably the most portable way on POSIX, but some OSs have recently added system-calls to get random data (so access to `/dev` can be restricted).

Comment: yeah, i'll probably include a copy of FreeBSD's arc4random.

Comment: I was thinking of Linux's `getrandom()` or openBSD's `getentropy()`. Arc4random is not a syscall as far as I know, so seeding the random generator is not as easy.

Comment: arc4random uses /dev/urandom to seed itself

Comment: In which case it `arc4random` needs access to `/dev`, so the application can't be chrooted/jailed.

Comment: rather than `time` (in seconds) you could use a micro-second value (such as `gettimeofday`), which is more difficult to predict. But it depend on machine precision and using entropy-based random API is clearly better.

Comment: @EOF, you can always add usage of getrandom on top of the existing code; in any case it won't be worse than the previous usage of srand/rand. I expect anything that has arc4random in libc, and a syscall such as `getentropy()`, to use the syscall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you worry about the challenge not being random enough and/or being predictable, there is always adding all those you can think up into a (long string) and calculating a one-way hash of that.

So a pseudo random number, time(), the IP address of the connection, the source port number, the username, a long string your challenge generator keeps secret, the pid, ... the more the merrier.

If any of those change, the resulting hash changes dramatically, and given the long string in there ... one would to need guess it or reverse the hash before the challenge becomes predictable.

It also makes for rather unique challenges (you'd need to find a collision in the hash for the challenge to not be unique).

That said, if the odds of the challenge recurring is mitigated (a pseudo random number generator does that IMHO), I think the purpose of the challenge is already met.

What I would worry about a lot in a challenge based authentication scheme is the storage of the secret password on the server. It can be done with salted storage and slow hashes, but many implementations just store the shared secret and that's IMHO a real bad idea.

Reference of an salted challenge response scheme: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salted_Challenge_Response_Authentication_Mechanism

Comment: The secret password is passed to my program; I don't care about storing it. The bad news: I'm implementing a well-known protocol (VNC) so I need to know it in clear. The good news: it's okay for the password to be once-only, so it doesn't have to be stored anywhere at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your hash and password are both good, it should not really matter if the challenge is predictable or not. The challenge is public knowledge once it has been submitted. The most important thing is never to repeat the challenge as a response could have been intercepted.

As I see it, a simple incrementing nonce could work here if you could keep it monotonically increasing.

Or perhaps there is some vulnerability here that I don't see?

Comment: A predictable challenge can be used for a replay attack.

Comment: @PaoloBonzini please explain?